# What is the equivalent statement in bigquery to set search_path?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know the equivalent statement of to set search_path to a schema in bigquery.

In Redshift we use set search_path to schema_name;
In SQL Server we use the statement USE Schema_name;

Could someone let me know how to go about the same in bigquery

I haven't been able to find out much in the documentation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think you need it? what is your use case?

Comment: I would like to make it more convenient for me to write my code. If there is a way that I can use just a one level name for a table, I would like to have that option. It is sometimes frustrating to write a three level name every single time.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL keyword `USE` is not supported when using BigQuery, the supported SQL query syntax is contained in this document[1]. 
Also the supported legacy syntax here[2].

As querying a BigQuery dataset requires referencing  the project to which the dataset is associated, there is no way to directly reference the dataset without using the project name, therefore there is no equivalent in BigQuery to `USE [schema]`. Querying a dataset via one of the client libraries requires the use of [project_name].[dataset].[table] notation.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#using-clause
[2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#functions

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there is no direct equivalent for USE statement!

Meantime, in Jobs.insert API – there is an optional defaultDataset property that user can set to specify the default dataset to use for unqualified table names in the query.

[image]

Note: In above example, projectId is optional and thus behavior of unqualified dataset names is still not covered

You can check if this property is implemented in your preferred client library

As of UI - in both (Classic and New) BigQuery UI – this feature looks like not implemented/used – rather the current project is used to qualify unqualified dataset.table references but there is no way to set default dataset to resolve unqualified table references instead “missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.” error message is presented

[image]

[image]

So, as you can see, while feature is available – it is up to client to use/implement it or ignore

As an example - Goliath (BigQuery Explorer, part of Potens.io Suite of tools for BigQuery) sets default dataset based on current project and active dataset.

For example, in below screenshot – **flights** dataset is active thus the message "*Not found: Table cloud-training-demos:demos.xxx was not found in location US*"

[image]

While if you change active dataset to **demos** – the message will be – "*Not found: Table cloud-training-demos:demos.xxx was not found in location US*"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apparently do this to set the dataset searched by default:

```
SET @@dataset_id = 'somedataset';
```

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/system-variables